# How do I make double-checked locking syntax less verbose?

Tags: c#, locking

In C#, I have the following extremely verbose syntax for pulling a simple list of items from a database:

```
if (malls == null)
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        if (malls == null)
        {
            using (var session = NhibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                malls = session.CreateCriteria<Mall>()
                    .AddOrder(Order.Asc("Name")).List<Mall>();

                CacheManager.Set(CACHE_KEY, malls, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(CACHE_DURATION));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm aware of the benefits of double checked locking and I strongly support its use, but it seems incredibly verbose. Can you recommend any syntax shortcuts or styles that might clean it up a bit?

Comment: I would be interested in the supposed benefits of this pattern.  In my experience people severely misunderstand this pattern and it's implications (for instance, it doesn't work reliably on Mono due to memory model differences).  I haven't ever seen it's supposed benefits live up to all of the problems it causes.

Comment: The method in question will pull about 5000 records from a database to cache in memory. It's going to be used in a heavily trafficked ASP.NET site and may be called several hundred to several thousand times per second, so I definitely want to cache the data and at the same time avoid another thread re-pulling the data simply because the null check failed before the lock was acquired. Also, due to the heavy access to the function, I cannot merely remove the first null check because the consequent unnecessary locking would bury the app.

Comment: @Chris, have you **proved** this is actually a benefit to your application?  Or that using a simple lock is a problem?

Comment: Initial profiling of the app using jmeter and dotTrace put this method near the top in terms of thread time (not necessarily CPU usage). The app hasn't hit real world traffic yet, but if the method is a top consumer in initial testing, I'd like to make it as efficient as possible

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Presumably you're using double-checked locking because you have a resource which you want initialized in a lazy, threadsafe manner.

Double-checked locking is a *mechanism* for achieving that, but as you've correctly noted, the verbosity of the mechanism is thoroughly overwhemling the meaning of the code.

When you have a mechanism that is obscuring the meaning, *hide the mechanism by creating an abstraction*. One way to do that would be to create a "lazy threadsafe instantiation" class and pass a delegate to it which does the operation you would like done in a lazy, threadsafe manner.

However, there's a better way. The better way is to not do that work yourself, but rather to let a world-class expert on threading do it for you. That way you don't have to worry about getting it right. Joe Duffy has to worry about getting it right. As Joe wisely says, rather than repeating the locking mechanism all over the place, write it once and then use the abstraction.

Joe's code is here:

http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,a2787ef6-ade6-4818-846a-2b2fd8bb752b.aspx

and a variation of this code will ship in the next version of the base class library.

Comment: By "people like Joe", do you mean "Microsoft employees"?  Yes, we pay our employees -- like Joe -- to write code. :-)

Answer (score 1):

To cut down on noise you can do this:

```
public List<Mall> Malls()
{
    EnsureMallsInitialized();
    return malls;
}

private void EnsureMallsInitialized()
{
    if (malls == null) // not set
    lock (_lock)       // get lock
    if (malls == null) // still not set
    {
        InitializeMalls();
    }        
}

private void InitializeMalls()
{
    using (var session = NhibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    {
        malls = session.CreateCriteria<Mall>()
            .AddOrder(Order.Asc("Name")).List<Mall>();

        CacheManager.Set(CACHE_KEY, malls, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(CACHE_DURATION));
    }
}
```